# Execute operations given by the user with(out) eval()

Tags: python, eval

I have a number of python codes that manipulate large files. In some of them I perform operations among columns or select upon their content. As the input files can have different structures, the operations are provided though command line with a syntax like this `c3 + c5 -1` or `(c3<4) & (c5>4)` (or combinations). `c4` is interpreted as *forth column of the input file*.

My files look something like this ('input_file.txt'):

```
21.3   4321.34   34.12   4   343.3  2  324
34.34  67.56     764.45  2   54.768 6  45265
986.96 87.98     234.09  1   54.456 3  5262
[...]
```

Let's say that I want to sum column 4 with column 5 and subtract 1.
I would do

```
import re
import numpy as np

operation = "c3 + c5 -1"  #in reality given from command line
pattern = re.compile(r"c(\d+?)") # compile the regex that matches the column number
# get the actual expression to evaluate
to_evaluate = pattern.sub("ifile[:,\\1]", operation) 
#to_evaluate is: "ifile[:,3] + ifile[:,5] -1"

ifile = np.loadtxt('input_file.txt')
result = eval(to_evaluate)  #evaluate the operation required
print(result)
# do the rest
```

Output

> [5, 7, 3, ...]

I came up with this implementation because:

1. it's easy to write and to modify if I want to change the method for reading files (at the moment I can decide to use `numpy` or `pandas`) or if I want to add operations
2. gives me a lot of freedom on what I can do. I can treat `c3 + c5 -1`, `(c3<4) & (c5>4)` or `(c2+c4)>0` in the same way.
3. I have the same signature in all my codes: it's less likely to make mistakes

I'm aware that `eval` can be unsafe (although for now I'm the only user of these codes) and can be slower than the corresponding code, but I couldn't think of a better way.

Is anyone aware of better/safer ways to implement such operations?

extra edit: if it matters, I'm running python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a safer eval

```
def safe_eval(eval_str, variable_dict = None):
    '''welll... mostly safe:
        http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html
    '''
    if variable_dict == None:
        variable_dict = {}
    return eval(eval_str, {"__builtins__" : None}, variable_dict)
```

Although it will never make it perfectly safe from someone who knows python very well 
(see http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html for an example)

Your application is confusing to me though, so I'm not sure how much more I can help you!

---

I'm not sure if this will help solve what you are doing, but one thing you can do is compile all the functions in a module into a dictionary.

So you could compile the functions you want to use through something like:

```
module_dict = {}
for n in dir(module):
 module_dict[n] = eval('module.'+n)
```

(I believe this functionality is standard in python 3. i.e. all modules module dicionaries can be accessed.) This puts all the function calls in dictionary form which speeds up calls. It also solves the eval safety issues.

If you are trying to use operations like '+' or '=' you can get their function calls from object.**add** and object.**eq**. You could store those calls into your string syntax.

Not sure if that helps.

Comment: thanks for the function and the link, very interesting. If you can tell me what you find confusing I can try to edit the question an make it clearer

Comment: I just don't understand these file operations. Hmm... I have an idea. See above shortly.

Comment: would help if I add a few lines of a mock file and the answer I expect?

Comment: Anything you can do to clarify your question would probably help people answer it :)

Comment: I (think I) get your point in the edit. The main issue that I see is that it can get complicated if when using parentheses.

Comment: Could you handle paraenthesis calls by recursively calling your processing function (i.e. anything in a paranthesis becomes a value that calls the function itself).  Just an idea